# Как узнать список пользователей в mysql?

Tags: mysql

Установил `mysql`. А имя пользователя установить при установке не предлагалось. Только пароль. Я слышал, что можно узнать логин или вовсе добавить юзера как админа и решить эту проблему. Но не могу нагуглить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне решить данную проблему. С `root` без пароля тоже не логинится.

По ответу `Grigoriy Sandu` [reset root passwd](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/)

```
SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;
```

Тоже не получается. Переустановил. И опять мне пароля не предложил. И опять не могу никак войти.

Comment: А root с паролем, который ты указал при установке?

Comment: @Qwertiy неа...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset root passwd : https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/

SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;

Comment: Надо было ещё мускул от `sudo` запускать)